# Find all specific element in dom and add class on next element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to find all `img` in a page and if the next tag is `div.txt` add class `test` on this next element.

I've tried this but I dont know why it isnt working:

```
for(i = 0; i < $('.page img').length; i++){
    $('.page').find('img:eq('+i+')').next('.txt').addClass('teste');    
}
```

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you really just write  `('.page img').length`  without a `$` in front of it? You say you want to add the class `test` but you add `teste`.

Comment: Is it 'test' or 'teste' ?

Answer (score 1):

You were missing $. No need to loop, use .each() like this:

```
$('.page img').each(function(){
    $(this).next('.txt').addClass('teste');    
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Isnt `.each()` a loop?

Comment: Yes it is. What I meant was no need to loop yourself, let JQuery do it :)